# Mail gem: how to set an email to "read"?

Tags: ruby, email

I have to write an email importer in Ruby, and I stumbled over the very great looking Mail gem for Ruby 1.9. I know how to iterate over unread messages, but I don't know how to mark them as read (the documentation is exhaustive, but I don't really know what to look after):

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :imap,
    address:    email_account.email_server.host,
    port:       email_account.email_server.port,
    user_name:  email_account.address,
    password:   email_account.password,
    enable_ssl: email_account.email_server.ssl
end

emails = Mail.find(
  what: :first,
  count: 3,
  order: :asc
)

emails.each do |email|
  # Do some stuff and then mark as read!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy thing to do

```
Mail.defaults do
    retriever_method :imap,
    address:    email_account.email_server.host,
    port:       email_account.email_server.port,
    user_name:  email_account.address,
    password:   email_account.password,
    enable_ssl: email_account.email_server.ssl
end

Mail.find(what: :first, count: 3, order: :asc) do |email, imap, uid|
    # Do some stuff
    # ..
    # mark as read
    imap.uid_store( uid, "+FLAGS", [Net::IMAP::SEEN] )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this..

[Mark IMAP Email as Read/Unread (Seen/Unseen):](http://www.example-code.com/ruby/imap_markAsRead.asp)

```
require 'chilkat'

imap = Chilkat::CkImap.new()

#  Anything unlocks the component and begins a fully-functional 30-day trial.
success = imap.UnlockComponent("Anything for 30-day trial")
if (success != true)
    print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
    exit
end

#  Connect to an IMAP server.
success = imap.Connect("mail.chilkatsoft.com")
if (success != true)
    print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
    exit
end

#  Login
success = imap.Login("myLogin","myPassword")
if (success != true)
    print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
    exit
end

#  Select an IMAP mailbox
success = imap.SelectMailbox("Inbox")
if (success != true)
    print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
    exit
end

#  Set PeekMode so that downloaded messages are not
#  automatically marked as seen.
imap.put_PeekMode(true)

#  The NumMessages property contains the number of messages
#  in the currently selected mailbox.
numMsgs = imap.get_NumMessages()
if (numMsgs == 0)
    exit
end

for i in 1 .. numMsgs
    #  Download each email by sequence number (not UID)

    # email is a CkEmail
    email = imap.FetchSingle(i,false)
    if (email == nil )
        print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
        exit
    end

    #  If desired, mark the email as SEEN.  There are two
    #  ways to do it:

    #  1) Set the flag directly by using the sequence number
    #  Indicate that we are passing a sequence number and
    #  not a UID:
    bIsUid = false
    #  Set the SEEN flag = 1 to mark the email as SEEN,
    #  or set it to 0 to mark it as not-seen.
    success = imap.SetFlag(i,bIsUid,"SEEN",1)
    if (success != true)
        print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
        exit
    end

    #  2) Alternatively, we can use the email object.
    #  When an email is downloaded from the IMAP server
    #  Chilkat will add a "ckx-imap-uid" header to the email.
    #  This makes it possible to know the UID associated with
    #  the email.  (This is not the sequence number, which may change
    #  from session to session, but the UID which does not change.
    #  The SetMailFlag method is identical to SetFlag, except
    #  it gets the UID from the ckx-imap-uid header.
    #  For example:
    success = imap.SetMailFlag(email,"SEEN",1)
    if (success != true)
        print imap.lastErrorText() + "\n";
        exit
    end

end

#  Disconnect from the IMAP server.
imap.Disconnect()
```

or try this..

[Mark All Unread Mail As Read In Ruby](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/mark-all-unread-mail-read-ruby)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm sure there are ways embedded into the Mail gem, and I'd like to use them.

Comment: Hmm.. I think, there is no option to make read/unread the mails using the gem Mail. We need to implement that. If you are using the gmail as your mail client then you can use ruby-gmail gem (https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail). It's working make read/unread the mails. I'll go to work on the task read/unread mails (mail gem).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm a bit confused now - isn't the Mail gem a widely used and well proven gem? If so, why's there no option to make mails marked as read/unread? Seems very odd to me.

Comment: I found this: `imap.uid_store(uid, "+FLAGS", [:Seen])`, and I could use this. But I don't know how to get to the `imap` object of the Mail gem.

Comment: Yes, of-course. You are right. You are finding the imap#uid_store syntax only. There were not implemented the read/unread (seen/unseen) features yet.. Please see the following link. http://tinypaste.com/8c8a6b22

Comment: Thank you. I tried to monkey patch, look [here](http://tinypaste.com/1dc381d7), but it results in `Net::IMAP::DataFormatError: "8B7C4FDF-11F0-4AB3-B39F-1E21B372670A@josh.ch"`, maybe I'm not using the right UID (isn't `email.message_id` the right one?)...?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Mail.find(keys: ['NOT','SEEN']) do |email, imap, uid|
  imap.uid_store(uid, "+FLAGS", [:Seen])
end
```

Comment: I suppose `UNSEEN` filter also works.